# Rewrite or Redirect this with htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a lot of external links that is point to this http://example.com/sub-dir/post_name/2010/10/10/

and I would like to redirect them to this http://example.com/sub-dir/2010/10/10/post_name/

The first link is old url structure,and the second one is new url structure.

code that I have tried:

```
Redirect 301 /sub-dir/([a-z0-9-]+)/(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})/ http://example.com/sub-dir/$2/$1/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([\w\-]+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/? /$2/$3/$4/$1 [R=301]
```

The condition matches go like:

- one or more word/hyphen characters
- a slash
- one or more number characters
- a slash
- one or more number characters
- a slash
- one or more number characters

It then redirects the user (with a status code of 301) to a different arrangement of those sub-patterns.

See [mod_rewrite#RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Comment: thank you,can you explain a little bit that please ? I would like to learn :)

Comment: @user303832:  Hopefully that explanation of the pattern helps a bit.

Comment: Hi @Tim Cooper,yes it explains,but why mine isn't working,I have done similar like yours?

Comment: I have change my question a little bit,because I have sub dir,and I have tried your code,it didn't work for me.maybe because I have sub dir,I'm not sure is that imporant?

Comment: @user303832:  `Redirect` doesn't accept regular expressions.  For that, you should take a look at [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch).

Comment: Hi,thank you,I didn't know that,I will try with you script to edit a little bit,because now,it doesn't work for me at the moment.